# Differential Equation Birth-Death Rate Model

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on the following problem:

Birth and death rates of animal populations typically are not constant; instead, they vary periodically with the passage of seasons.

Find P(t) if the population P satisfies the initial value problem:
$$ \frac{dP}{dt}=(k+bcos(2πt))P $$
$$ P(0)=P_0 $$

I've solved for P(t) using separation of variables, and then found the constant C using the initial condition, but was unsuccessful. Is this the correct approach?

$$ \frac{dP}{P}=k+bcos(2πt) dt $$
$$ \int{dP/P} = \int k+bcos(2πt) dt$$
$$ ln(P) = kt+btsin(2πt) + C $$
$$ P(t) = Ce^{kt+btsin(2πt)} $$
$$ P_0 = Ce^{0} $$
$$ C=P_0 $$
$$ P(t) = P_0e^{kt+bt \sin(2πt)} $$

Comment: Oops, everything is okay, with the exception of the integral. $b$ is a constant, so what is the integral of the $\cos 2 \pi t~ dt$ term? Fix that and the rest is good.

Comment: You shouldn't have $t$ in $bt\sin(2\pi t)$ since the antidervative of $\cos(t)$ is $\sin(t)$. Other than that, it's perfect.

Comment: Ah -- so the correct integral of bcos2πt is (bsin2πt)/2π. Got way to confident in my integration abilities.

Comment: @Bob: You got it! Great job, keep up the good work! Regards